# How to create the webhook receiver kind of in Xamarin form(Android and iOS)?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to create the Xamarin Form app for both android and iOS in which when something events occurs or data update on server than server call my xamarin app and i will perform some task in my app. Push notification and SignalR both are not suitable for my case. is there anything like webhook in Xamarin form. There are many example for Web application but nothing i found in case of mobile application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `RESTful web service` as a webhook.

Representational State Transfer (REST) is an architectural style for building web services. REST requests are made over HTTP using the same HTTP verbs that web browsers use to retrieve web pages and to send data to servers.

More informations you can refer to this website:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest